# using Graphql - com.graphql-java-kickstart with spring webflux return types

Tags: java, graphql, spring-webflux, graphql-java

I want to implement a GraphQL spring-webflux based application.
I have tried code as shown in the sample : https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/samples/tree/master/spring-boot-webflux

The query "hello" is returning the toString() value of Mono and not the String that Mono is holding:
[hello Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz8KW.png)

If I try a Mono of a custom object (Item here), I get an error like below:
graphql.kickstart.tools.ResolverError: Expected source object to be an instance of 'com.example.demo.pojo.Item' but instead got 'reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust'

My build.gradle file is as below:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
id 'java'
}

dependencies {
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
implementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:11.0.0'
compileOnly 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-java-tools:11.0.1'
runtimeOnly 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:11.0.0'
runtimeOnly 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:voyager-spring-boot-starter:11.0.0'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
```

}

Returning a CompletableFuture works but I would prefer using Mono/Flux.

Would appreciate any sample/pointer on using webflux with GraphQL.

Comment: what is `graphiql`? and what object is `com.example.demo.pojo.Item`

Comment: graphiql is a tool to interact with a graphQL application in a user friendly way.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was due to the incorrect dependencies. The sample is may be outdated. Below is what worked for me in case someone finds it helpful:

in build.gradle:

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
implementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-kickstart-spring-boot-starter-webflux:11.1.0'
implementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-kickstart-spring-boot-starter-tools:11.1.0'

This is able to handle reactive return types in GraphQL response.
Thanks for anyone who spent time on this.